# Como acceder al valor de un timer creado por console.time()

Tags: javascript

he estado haciendo un pequeno "juego" con `JS` ...

```js
"use strict";
// move status part
let zombieArray = [];
let reset_button = document.getElementById("reset_button");
let zombies_container = document.getElementById("cursor_container");
let mouse_status = document.getElementById("mouse__pos");
let button = document.getElementById("button");
let last_zombie_delay = 100;
let last_zombie_id = 0;

function getRandom(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}
// click button code
class Zombie {
    constructor(position, delay, id) {
        this.position = position;
        this.id = id;
        this.delay = delay;
        this.ref = document.createElement("div");
        this.ref.setAttribute("id", `zombie_${this.id}`);
        this.ref.style.left = `${this.position[0]}px`;
        this.ref.style.backgroundColor = `#${getRandom(5, 9)}${getRandom(
            5,
            9
        )}${getRandom(5, 9)}`;
        this.ref.style.top = `${this.position[1]}px`;
        this.ref.style.transition = `top ${this.delay}ms, left ${this.delay}ms,transform 0.5s `;

        this.ref.style.transitionTimingFunction =
            "cubic-bezier(0.44, 0.47, 0.73, 0.72)";
        this.position = position;
        this.pos_diff = [getRandom(0, 100), getRandom(0, 100)];
    }
    updatePosition(new_position) {
        // se movera al zombie a new_position aplicando la diferencia de espacio del mismo
        this.position = [
            new_position[0] - this.pos_diff[0],
            new_position[1] - this.pos_diff[1],
        ];
        this.ref.style.left = `${this.position[0]}px`;
        this.ref.style.top = `${this.position[1]}px`;
    }
    updateRelativePosition(ref_pos, pos_move) {
        // se movera al zombie a ref_pos aplicando pos_move
        let random = getRandom(0, 50);
        if (random > 20) {
            this.position = [
                ref_pos[0] - pos_move[0],
                ref_pos[1] - pos_move[1],
            ];
        } else {
            this.position = [
                ref_pos[0] + pos_move[0],
                ref_pos[1] + pos_move[1],
            ];
        }
        this.ref.style.left = `${this.position[0]}px`;
        this.ref.style.top = `${this.position[1]}px`;
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    if (zombieArray.length === 0) {
        reset_button.style.left = "80%";
    }
    last_zombie_id++;
    last_zombie_delay += 50;
    let new_zombie = new Zombie([-800, 500], last_zombie_delay, last_zombie_id);
    zombieArray.push(new_zombie);
    zombies_container.appendChild(new_zombie.ref);
});

document.addEventListener("mousemove", (event) => {
    let new_position = [event.x, event.y];
    zombieArray.forEach(function (cursor) {
        cursor.updatePosition(new_position);
    });
});

reset_button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    while (zombieArray.length > 0) {
        zombies_container.removeChild(zombieArray.pop().ref);
    }
    last_zombie_delay = 100;
    last_zombie_id = 0;
    reset_button.style.left = "-20%";
});
window.setInterval(() => {
    zombieArray.forEach((zombie) => {
        zombie.updateRelativePosition(zombie.position, [
            getRandom(-10, 10),
            getRandom(-10, 10),
        ]);
    });
}, 150);
```

```css
:root {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#button,
#reset_button {
width : 15vw;
height : 7vh;
font-size : 5vh;
text-align : center;

    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left: 2%;
    top: 5%;
    transition: transform 0.5s, left 0.5s;
    user-select: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

#reset_button {
    left: -20%;
}
.cursor_container > * {
    padding: 30px;
    background-color: #0f0;
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50px !important;
    transition-property: left, top, transform;
    transition-duration: 0.5s;
    transform: scale(0.3, 0.3);
}

:root {
    background-color: #222;
}

#button:hover,
#reset_button:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2, 1.2);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>Titulo de la pagina</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="button">Generar zombie</div>
            <div id="reset_button">Resetear conteo</div>
            <div class="cursor_container" id="cursor_container"></div>
            <div class="pepe"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Pues ahora mi idea es que los "zombies" solo se muevan random cuando el cursor este quieto, el unico modo que se me ocurrio para hacer eso es iniciar un timer cuando el mouse se mueva, y todo el tiempo comprobar si ya paso cierto limite, en ese caso mover los zombies, algo asi como ...

```
if (mouse_move_timer > 1000){
     // mover zombies random
}
```

Este codigo tendria que ponerlo en el `setInterval()`, ahora el problema es que el `console.timeLog()` (el cual es el unico modo que conozco para hacer timers, soy bastante novato en `js`) , no retorna el tiempo, simplemente lo imprime. ***Teniendo esto en cuenta: como podria acceder al valor de un timer creado por console.time()?***

Comment: El método `console.time()` no se utiliza para lo que tu deseas hacer. Debes crear tu propio *timer*.

Comment: como podria hacerlo? (puedes dejarlo en una respuesta)

Answer (score 1):

Creo que la mejor idea para detectar al mouse quieto es la propuesta en tu pregunta. Voy a introducir algunos conceptos antes de mostrar como puede ser resuelto.

##### Timers en javascript

Las unicas formas que conozco de crear timers en javascript es con [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setInterval)(llamar cada...) y [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)(llamar una vez luego de).

Sin embargo, no podemos reiniciar ni pausar estos timers. Solo eliminarlos con las respectivas funciones clearTimeout y clearInterval.

Supongo que por eso, te han comentado que debes crear tu propio timer.

##### Creando nuestro timer

Sin embargo, podemos utilizar setTimeout y setInterval como material de construcción para crear un Timer que pueda ser reiniciado y que sirva para crear tareas repetitivas cuando el mouse está quieto:

- Cada vez que se detecta un movimiento de mouse, eliminar la "tarea repetitiva" ejecutada cuando el mouse está quieto y "reiniciar" el timer encargado de detectar la falta de movimiento. Lo más cercano a reiniciar el timer es eliminar el timer anterior (si fue creado) y creando uno nuevo usando los mismos argumentos. Ejemplo de esto: `setTimeout(...args);clearTimeout(id);setTimeout(...args)`.
- Si el tiempo pasó, creamos una "tarea repetitiva" usando setInterval que se ejecute cada x milisegundos.

##### Ejemplo

Un ejemplo de ésto es:

```html
<body>
    <div id="texto"></div>

    <script>
        class QuietMouseDetector{
            constructor(callback, quietDelay, interval){
                this.callback = callback
                this.quietDelay = quietDelay
                this.interval = interval
            }

            onTimeout(){
                delete this.timer
                this.repeater = setInterval(this.callback, this.interval)
            }

            start(){
                if(this.repeater !== undefined){
                    clearInterval(this.repeater)
                    delete this.repeater
                }
                
                if(this.timer !== undefined){
                    clearTimeout(this.timer)
                }

                this.timer = setTimeout(() => this.onTimeout(), this.minQuietDelay)

            }
        }

        let elem = document.getElementById("texto")
        let timer = new QuietMouseDetector(() => elem.innerText = "mouse quieto", 1000, 1000)

        addEventListener("mousemove", event => {
            timer.start()
            elem.innerText = "mouse " + event.offsetX + ", " + event.offsetY
        })
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: andas reviviendo post de hace 2 años ajajajaja... no hay ningun challenge nuevo cierto???

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover Asi es xD, y estoy aprovechando que estoy aprendiendo js para buscar nuevos y viejos challenges!